# jspdf.addHTML throwing an error

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf, html2canvas

Using jsPDF in angular 2, I am running this code on a button click:

```
generatePDF(){
    const options = {'pagesplit': true}
    this.pdf.addHTML(this.id.nativeElement, 10, 10, options, function(){
      this.pdf.save('test.pdf')
    }); 
}
```

onClick the generatePDF function is called and throws this error without generating the pdf:
**html2canvas: onrendered option is deprecated, html2canvas returns a Promise with the canvas as the value**
I have checked the official documentation of [jsPDF](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML), it does say it is deprecated.

I would appreciate some help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

jsPDF need to be updated to match HTML2Canvas library, they removed the onrendered callback and changed it to use Promise, use an old version of HTML2Canvas "0.5.0-beta4" or less and it will work.

Edit: new library called html2pdf is out, check it